# php call_user_func_array parameter

Tags: php, function, callback

The `$current_user` has the value:

```
New_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_login] => admin
        )

    [ID] => 1
    [caps] => Array
        (
        )
 )
```

The function call:

```
call_user_func_array( array( &$current_user, 'can_do' ), $args );
```

Which functions are called in this statement?

Comment: `$current_user`'s `can_do()`. Can you make this a bit more concrete? What is your situation and/or problem?

Answer (score 0):

This will call the `can_do` method of `$current_user` object's `class`.

See the given examples in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)